# AS3: How would I make the answers pop up green or red if the answer was right or not in a quiz?

Tags: actionscript-3

I got this code from my tutor and the quiz itself works; you can select answers and it traces that you've done so, but it doesn't recognise if you've pressed the right answer or not.

I want it to highlight green or red depending on if the right answer was clicked; but i don't know what code to right as i'm still a beginner at Action script. The correct answer is specified in the XML I just have to reference it to the code i think. Any help?

Here is the code:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import TabAnswer;
    import IconNext;

    public class Quiz extends MovieClip {

        private var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat  ;
        private var question:TextField = new TextField  ;
        private var answer:TabAnswer;
        private var answers:Array = new Array  ;
        private var quiz:XML;
        private var next:IconNext = new IconNext  ;
        private var currentQuestion:int = 0;

        public function Quiz() {
            // constructor code
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader  ;
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("quiz.xml"));
        }

        private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void {
            // make an XML instance using XML data passed to this function
            quiz = new XML(e.target.data);
            trace(quiz);
            //set some text formatting
            tf.size = 20;
            tf.color = 0x000000;
            tf.font = "Tw Cen MT Condensed";
            //create a textfield for question information
            addChild(question);
            question.setTextFormat(tf);
            question.multiline = true;
            question.width = question.textWidth;
            question.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            question.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            question.text = quiz.question[currentQuestion].description;
            for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                var answer = new TabAnswer  ;
                answers.push(answer);
                addChild(answers[a]);
                answers[a].x = question.x;
                answers[a].y = question.y + question.height + answer.height + ((a * answer.height) * 1.5);
                answers[a].answer.text = quiz.question[currentQuestion].answers.answer[a];
                answers[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,answerSelected);
            }
            addChild(next);
            next.x = stage.stageWidth - next.width * 1.3;
            next.y = stage.stageHeight - next.height * 2.3;
            next.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,nextQuestion);
        }

        private function answerSelected(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(e.currentTarget.answer.text);
            //check to see if the answer that has been pressed, matches the
            //correctAnswer node in the quiz xml question
        }

        private function nextQuestion(e:MouseEvent):void {
            currentQuestion++;
            getQuestion(currentQuestion);
        }

        private function getQuestion(questionToGet:int):void {
            question.text = quiz.question[questionToGet].description;
            for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                answers[a].answer.text = quiz.question[questionToGet].answers.answer[a];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the XML so it will make it a little more sense how it's working maybe?:

```
    </question>
<question>
    <description>What is the role of the player that throws the ball to the batter?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Catcher</answer>
       <answer>Pitcher</answer>
       <answer>Shortfield</answer>
       <answer>Umpire</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Pitcher</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>How many bases are there?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>5</answer>
       <answer>2</answer>
       <answer>4</answer>
       <answer>3</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>3</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>What is it called when a batter hits the ball out of the field and runs around all the bases?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Full round</answer>
       <answer>Touchdown</answer>
       <answer>Home Run</answer>
       <answer>Goal</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Home Run</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>How many strikes is it for the batter to be out?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>3</answer>
       <answer>4</answer>
       <answer>1</answer>
       <answer>6</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>3</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>What is the batting technique called when a batter wants a quick base run?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Punt</answer>
       <answer>Strongarm</answer>
       <answer>Bunt</answer>
       <answer>Hit</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Bunt</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>Who is usually the team leader in a game?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Pitcher</answer>
       <answer>Center Fielder</answer>
       <answer>Second Baseman</answer>
       <answer>Catcher</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Catcher</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>There were 4 stategies mentioned, Sliding/Diving, Force Outs,Tag Outs, what is the last one?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Robbing</answer>
       <answer>Stealing</answer>
       <answer>Force Play</answer>
       <answer>Cheating</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Stealing</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>When pitching the ball, the ball need to be over what?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>All of the home plate</answer>
       <answer>None of the home plate</answer>
       <answer>Some of the home plate</answer>
       <answer>To the side of the home plate</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Some of the home plate</correctAnswer>
    </question>

<question>
    <description>Who was rated the No.1 Baseball player of 2016?</description>
<answers>
       <answer>Manny Machando</answer>
       <answer>Chris Sale</answer>
       <answer>Bryce Harper</answer>
       <answer>Mike Trout</answer>
    </answers> 
    <correctAnswer>Mike Trout</correctAnswer>
    </question>
 </quiz>
```

Comment: I see you already know how to change font color. So your question is really how to check if the answer is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes! If i can see if the answer chosen was correct, then yeah, i could change the text box colour or something. I just dont know how to find that out?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You could have array of questions and array of answers. And if they are in the same order just compare array positions.

Comment: Or you could have array of objects which each have the q and matching answer as properties.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, i've just realised that about the answersArray part. it shoudlnt be there, ill update it now. The questions and answers are in a XML file.

Comment: If i'm honest, because i'm relatively new to this, whats the simplest/ easiest? Got to hand this assignment in on a Monday :/

Comment: quiz.question looks like an array you could use. Does the first question correspond with the first answer? I hope. That would make this very simple. So `quiz.question[3]` should have an answer in `answers[3]`. Is that how it works?

Comment: Ummm... okayy. so quiz.question is an array that would be used? How the code look? Sorry, i cant right code yet. I've added the XML so you can see it better, the answers dont mirror the order question number, but i could change that if it'll be easier? but after 4, that wouldn't work would it?

Comment: Doh! This is even easier. each question has 4 answers and 1 correct answer. So just check if the `e.currentTarget.answer.text == quiz.question.correctAnswer.text`.  If true, run you text cook changing code, or whatever.

Comment: Okay thank you! But the code you right comes back fine, but for some reason they're all saying false.... which is weird? Do you know why at all?

Comment: what are the trace statements coming out to in my answer?  It should say "correct answer is: Pitcher answer picked is:Pitcher" or something like that.  In which case it would be "true", but you say they are all false, so this trace statement should say something unexpected like "correct answer is; NaN answer picked is: null" or some weird garbage like that but it will help us figure out where the error is occuring.  Or it might say that the correct answer is "Peanuts and Cracker Jacks" which is the correct answer to a totally different question, which would tell us we are not linking them.

Comment: Using the code you provided me, it seems to not say anything other than the number I picked. However, when i // you 'if' statement, it was showing this: 9
correct answer is:  answer picked was: 9. it seems to not find what the correct answer is? I think? I am not sure why you if statement isn't working either? Does this oddly help in any way?

Comment: The if statement is working, but it evaluates to false each time so my method has a flaw. And you're probably right that it has to do with the "correctAnswer". I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function answerSelected ( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    trace ( e.currentTarget.answer.text );
    //check to see if the answer that has been pressed, matches the
    //correctAnswer node in the quiz xml question
    if (e.currentTarget.answer.text == quiz.question.correctAnswer.text)
       trace("correct answer is:",quiz.question.correctAnswer.text,"answer picked was:",e.currentTarget.answer.text);
       // change text color, or whatever. 
    }
}
```

Try this.  Let me know what it traces out if it isn't working.